# Google Signin with Firebase Auth on Android Cordova not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I spent hours trying to make Google Signin work on Android with Cordova (it was working on iOS / Web). I have followed these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

I was trying to use a custom Dynamic Link ("mydomain.com/link") and it was not working: after authenticating, the user was redirected to the website INSIDE the popup, instead of closing it and authenticate in the app.

So I decided to create a simple "myapp.page.link", but it was not working neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I simply deleted my custom Dynamic Link, and voila, it works!**

So you can use a custom domain for the `AUTH_DOMAIN`, but not for the `DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN`. Important: if you use a custom `AUTH_DOMAIN`, you will have to change manually the `authDomain` attribute in the firebase config of your app.

@Firebase team: I think it could be useful to update the doc to precise that:

- you cannot use custom Dynamic Link
- you cannot have several Dynamic Link active

And ideally, it would be ideal to explain how the Dynamic Link is used by Firebase Auth: I followed the explanation, thought that any dynamic link would do the trick, but since you do not explain how it works, it's extremely hard to guess that it is not the case, and that having several dynamic links can be an issue.

Comment: "you cannot have several Dynamic Link active" <- This comment helped me to figure out a problem I was investigating for more than 2 days. Thank you.